# Require certain number of checkboxes be checked

Tags: javascript, html, input, checkbox, require

I am displaying many images in a table and asking that users select five of them.

Here is a sample of one table row:

```
<tr>
        <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image21_flag" name="flag" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img21"/><label class="middlealign" for="Image21_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL21}" /></label>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image22_flag" name="flag" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img22"/><label class="middlealign" for="Image22_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL22}" /></label>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image23_flag" name="flag" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img23"/><label class="middlealign" for="Image23_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL23}" /></label>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image24_flag" name="flag" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img24"/><label class="middlealign" for="Image24_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL24}" /></label>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image25_flag" name="flag" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img25"/><label class="middlealign" for="Image25_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL25}" /></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And the script I am using to ensure no more than five are selected:

```
$("input[name=flag]").change(function(){
var max= 5;
if( $("input[name=flag]:checked").length == max ){
    $("input[name=flag]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("input[name=flag]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
}else{
     $("input[name=flag]").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

How can I require that at least five are selected?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use jQuery, but you can use a `document.querySelectorAll()` to retrieve all your checkboxes, and use example [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to have an array that contains only the checked checkboxes and check that the array size is greater than or equal to 5.

Example :

```js
const checkboxArray = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
const checkedArray = Array.from(checkboxArray).filter(item => item.checked)
if (checkedArray.length > 5) {
  // More than 5 checkbox checked, do something
}
```

Note : This is possible to get checked input in css with `:checked`
See : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
$(function() { 
  $('input[name="flag[]"]').change(function(event) {
    var max = 5;
    if ($('input[name="flag[]"]:checked').length==max)
      $('input[name="flag[]"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
    else
      $('input[name="flag[]"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  });
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    if($('input[name="flag[]"]:checked').length!=5) {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.alert("Please select exactly five images");
      return false;
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image21_flag" name="flag[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img21" /><label class="middlealign" for="Image21_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL21}" /></label>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image22_flag" name="flag[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img22" /><label class="middlealign" for="Image22_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL22}" /></label>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image23_flag" name="flag[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img23" /><label class="middlealign" for="Image23_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL23}" /></label>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image24_flag" name="flag[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img24" /><label class="middlealign" for="Image24_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL24}" /></label>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"><input id="Image25_flag" name="flag[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="img25" /><label class="middlealign" for="Image25_flag"><img onerror="imgError(this);" src="${URL25}" /></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

> I am displaying many images in a table and asking that users select
> five of them. [...] How can I require that at least five are selected?

There are many different approaches to this, but one approach would be to keep an active log of how many checkboxes are and aren't checked and then, every time an action requires a response, check that live total and respond accordingly.

**Working Example:**

```js
// GET DOM ELEMENTS
const myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
const myCheckboxes = [... myForm.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')];
const mySubmitButton = myForm.querySelector('input[type="button"]');

// INITIALISE CHECKBOX LOG
let checkboxLog = 0;



 //**************************//
//**************************//



// FUNCTION logCheckedBoxes()
function logCheckedBoxes(event) {

  checkboxLog = (event.target.checked === true) ? checkboxLog + 1 : checkboxLog - 1;
  console.log(checkboxLog + ' boxes checked.');
}


// FUNCTION submitChoices()
function submitChoices() {

  if (checkboxLog === 5) {
    window.alert('5 Choices Submitted!');
  }
  
  else if (checkboxLog < 5) {
    window.alert("You need to select 5 boxes in total.\n\nPlease select " + (5 - checkboxLog) + " more boxes!");
  }
}



 //**************************//
//**************************//



// ADD LOGGING EVENT TO EACH CHECKBOX
for (checkbox of myCheckboxes) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', logCheckedBoxes, false);
}


// ADD EVENT TO SUBMIT BUTTON
mySubmitButton.addEventListener('click', submitChoices, false);
```

```html
<form>

<table>
<tr>
<td><input name="flag" type="checkbox" value="img21" /></td>
<td><input name="flag" type="checkbox" value="img22" /></td>
<td><input name="flag" type="checkbox" value="img23" /></td>
<td><input name="flag" type="checkbox" value="img24" /></td>
<td><input name="flag" type="checkbox" value="img25" /></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Submit Choices!" />
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```